# Implementing a non-causal Wiener filter

Tags: power-spectral-density, finite-impulse-response, digital-filters, wiener-filter, white-noise

I'm attempting to implement a non-causal Wiener filter for removing additive white noise from a measured signal. I've had some trouble and I have reduced my problem to a demonstration on simulated data with a specific question. Code is below ... my question is highlighting by the comment above it "`!!!! Question:`".

I think the crux of what I don't understand about the non-causal Wiener filter is - let's say my signal (everything zero-mean) is `s[k] = y[k] + n[k]`, where `y[k]` and `n[k]` are uncorrelated, and I construct the optimal filter `H = Ssy / Sss = Syy / Sss` where `Yhat = H * S` and `yhat` is the filter estimate of `y` ... then wouldn't the power spectral density of the filter output be `Syhat = |H|^2 * Sss = Syy^2 / Sss` which is NOT necessarily close to `Syy` ? Whereas if the filter were ~ `sqrt(H)` then the math would work out such that `Syhat = Syy`.

See plot below (one of outputs from example). In particular, it seems I need this extra `sqrt` factor when designing the filter in order for the output `yhat` PSD to line up with the true signal `y` PSD.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal

def ar1(npaths, ntime, beta, c, sigma):
    """
    Simulate an AR(1) process.

    Parameters
    ----------
    npaths : int
        Number of paths to simulate.
    ntime : int
        Number of time steps to simulate.
    beta : float
        Autoregressive parameter.
    c : float
        Constant term.
    sigma : float
        Standard deviation of the noise.

    Returns
    -------
    x : ndarray
        Array of shape (npaths, ntime) containing the simulated AR(1) process.
    """
    x = np.zeros((npaths, ntime))
    x[:, 0] = np.random.normal(0, sigma, npaths)
    for i in range(1, ntime):
        x[:, i] = beta * x[:, i - 1] + np.random.normal(c, sigma, npaths)
    return x

# Simulate signal + noise
fs, nt = 1e4, 50000
nperseg = 1024
t = np.arange(nt) / fs
y = np.squeeze(ar1(1, nt, 0.9, 0, 1))
noise = np.random.normal(0, 3, nt)
s = y + noise

# Compute PSD's
f, Pyy = scipy.signal.welch(y, fs=fs, nperseg=nperseg)
f, Pnn = scipy.signal.welch(noise, fs=fs, nperseg=nperseg)
f, Pss = scipy.signal.welch(s, fs=fs, nperseg=nperseg)

# Optimal Wiener filter frequency response
# G = Pys / Pss = Pyy / Pss
Gdes = Pyy / Pss
# !!!! Question: amplitude of filtered signal matches desired when I take np.sqrt here???
# I don't understand why we'd need the np.sqrt. Doesn't seem to match textbook def'n.
Hdes = np.sqrt(Gdes)
# To apply the filter to a time series, we design a FIR filter
# with the desired frequency response, and then apply it to the
# time series using scipy.signal.lfilter
numtaps = 201
bands = np.column_stack((f[:-1], f[1:]))
desired = np.column_stack((Hdes[:-1], Hdes[1:]))
bfilt, afilt = scipy.signal.firls(numtaps, bands, desired, fs=fs), [1]

# Bode plot of filter response
w, Hfilt = scipy.signal.freqz(bfilt, afilt, worN=8192, fs=fs)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
fig.suptitle("Least squares-based FIR filter design")
ax[0].loglog(f, np.abs(Hdes), 'k.', linewidth=1, label="Hdes")
ax[0].loglog(w, np.abs(Hfilt), 'r-', linewidth=1, label="Hfilt")
ax[1].semilogx(f, np.degrees(np.angle(Hdes)), 'k.', linewidth=1, label="Hdes")
ax[1].semilogx(w, np.degrees(np.angle(Hfilt)), 'r-', linewidth=1, label="Hfilt")
ax[0].grid(which="both", axis="both")
ax[1].grid(which="both", axis="both")
ax[1].set_xlabel("Frequency [Hz]")
ax[0].set_ylabel("Magnitude")
ax[1].set_ylabel("Phase [degrees]")

# Apply filter to signal
yhat = scipy.signal.lfilter(bfilt, afilt, s)
f, Phh = scipy.signal.welch(yhat, fs=fs, nperseg=nperseg)

# Time trace
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.suptitle("Time traces")
ax.plot(t, s, 'b-', linewidth=1, label="s = y + n")
ax.plot(t, y, 'k-', linewidth=1, label='y')
ax.plot(t, yhat, 'r-', linewidth=1, label="yhat")
ax.grid(which="both", axis="both")
ax.set_xlabel("Time [s]")
ax.set_ylabel("Amplitude (V)")
ax.legend()

# PSD's
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.loglog(f, Pss, 'b-', linewidth=1, label='s = y + n')
ax.loglog(f, Pyy, 'k-', linewidth=1, label='y')
ax.loglog(f, Pnn, 'c-', linewidth=1, label='n')
ax.loglog(f, Phh, 'r-', linewidth=1, label='yhat')
ax.grid(which="both", axis="both")
ax.set_xlabel("Frequency [Hz]")
ax.set_ylabel("PSD (V**2 / Hz)")
ax.legend()
fig.suptitle("Power spectral densities")

plt.show()
```

Comment: It's been long enough since I've designed a Wiener filter that I can't really call this an answer -- but your basic problem is that $H \ne \frac{S_{yy}}{S_{xx}}$.  For a purely causal filter, it would be the causal part of $\frac{S_{yy}}{S_{xx}}$ -- which has an absolute value of $\sqrt{\frac{S_{yy}}{S_{xx}}}$.  Because I'm rusty I can't give good details, but you need to express the end result as an impulne response, which will be the sum of the causal part of $\frac{S_{yy}}{S_{xx}}$ and the anti-causal (only valid for $\tau < 0$) part of $\frac{S_{yy}}{S_{xx}}$.

Comment: @TimWescott thank you for the pointer in the right direction, encouraging to know that there is likely something wrong! I've been digging into textbooks and test-driving more examples, no luck yet. I think a big disconnect for me is that I'm working with real world data, as opposed to a lot of the analytical solutions in the literature, that won't work for the actual problem I'm trying to solve - I have a situation where I have a wideband signal and ~white noise - I think the Wiener filter is the "right" answer and I need to get it to work! Will update my post if I find the answer.